# Difference between on_message_delete() and on_raw_message_delete()

Tags: python, discord.py

Can someone tell me what the difference between `on_raw_message_delete()`/`OnRawMessageDelete` and `on_message_delete()`/`OnMessageDelete` is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`on_raw_message_delete` unlike `on_message_delete` it's called regardless of the state of the internal cache.

Let's say you send a message, the bot caches it, but the bot suddenly restarts (the message won't be in the cache anymore), if you delete the message, `on_message_delete` won't be called, but `on_raw_message_delete` will.

Comment: Thanks :). Is there any advantage of `on_message_delete` over `on_raw_message_delete`?

Comment: There's is not imo, but that depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I replicated dank memer's pls snipe command and I think that `on_raw_message_delete` is much better in this case.